# Webservice consuming works only when debugging under VS IDE

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, webservice-client, service-reference

My WinForms VB.NET Application consumes a webservice to perform some queries. When running in debug mode under Visual Studio IDE, it works smoothly, but once deployed in client workstations (or even in my own workstation), it crashes with this message:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MyServiceReference.IMyService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I guess something that is present when debugging is missing in deployment, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Is it working in release mode locally?

Comment: Yes when run from VS IDE (with debugger attached). No when run from standalone .exe file in same computer.

Comment: can you show us the code in your app.config file?

Comment: Try removing the endpoints and add `compilation debug=true`

Comment: It might be a firewall or other IP filter mechanism preventing computers outside your company's network accessing the Web Service

Comment: @S.Dav, yes, there is. I told it wouldn't run outside my company's network. But the problem is happening in machines connected to it.

Comment: Do you deploy the app.config file to the client computers? It should be a file named `yourAppName.exe.config`.

Comment: @S.Dav, no, I never deployed this file. The program runned fine without it until I included this webservice reference. But if it is needed, I'll do it. But it is important to me it goes as a single .exe file, so that I use [Costura.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/) for packing all the DLLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good fellow [S.Dav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5396396/s-dav) commented above to alert that I should deploy **app.config** together with my .exe file to solve this issue. He is correct and if it was an answer, I'd accept it.

Besides, I found that I can hardcode service config data and it will work also.

So I replaced:

```
Dim myclient as New MyServiceReference.MyServiceClient
```

by

```
Dim myclient as New MyServiceReference.MyServiceClient(
    New BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None),
    New EndpointAddress("http://myservice.mysite.com/services/MyService.svc?wsdl"))
```

And *voilà*, it worked.

Many thanks for all those who tried and helped with this.